# My program prints the output occasionally although it is correctly compiled?

Tags: c++

My program here is to randomly assign the variables (number1, number2, number3, number4) to a number stored in `vector <int> number`. I want to make sure each number will appear only 1 time Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<int> number = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    int number1, number2, number3, number4;

    do {
        number1 = number[rand() % 4];
        number2 = number[rand() % 4];
        number3 = number[rand() % 4];
        number4 = number[rand() % 4];
        if (number2 != number1) {
            if (number3 != number1 && number3 != number2) {
                if (number4 != number1 && number4 != number2 && number4 != number3) {
                    cout << number1 << number2 << number3 << number4;
                }
            }
        }
    } while ((number1 + number2 + number3 + number4) != 26);
}
```

Sometimes it does print the right outputs to the terminal, but sometimes it just doesn't print anything and the program is terminated. I don't know why this happens, can anybody suggest me a solution ?

Comment: when the sum is 26 the program ends, and it only prints something when some other condition is satisfied

Comment: why do you think the code should always print something ?

Comment: The sum can be 26 without all 3 of your if() conditions being true. I added the same cout after the code and the first run it printed `6686` : [https://ideone.com/xtkSH7](https://ideone.com/xtkSH7)

Comment: I set the condition so that when the program finds the 4 numbers that add up to 26, it will print those numbers. So I think it should always has an output

Comment: The 6 + 6 + 8  + 6 would not be printed but is equal to 26. Did you want to make sure that each number appears only 1 time. If so std::shuffle() may be what you want instead of what you are doing: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) see the example at the bottom for a working program.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll have a try.

Comment: Once you've drawn a number, you can erase it from the vector. And so on, till only 1 number is left. Not very efficient, but easy to understand, and no `do` loop or a complicated condition will be necessary. The "pro" way is to use `std::shuffle`, as mentioned by @drescherjm but level "pro" may be too high for you. Write only code that you understand.

Comment: What this code suppose to do? It looks like that all `numberX` suppose to be unique, but this is possible only when `(number1 + number2 + number3 + number4) != 26` is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make sure each number will appear only 1 time

Rather than picking an index, you can [`shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) the selection.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> number = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    std::shuffle(number.begin(), number.end(), std::random_device{});
    std::cout << number[0] << " " << number[1] << " " << number[2] << " " << number[3] << std::endl;
}
```